# Generate Listview from items received as responses from server url

Tags: android, listview

I am making a portal sort of an app . I have used an api to receive update that i push in the listview. But with every new update i lose out on the news piece from previous response. Therefore i created a Database that stores the previous news items. Now the problem is that i get duplicate copies since the database stores the response again if the update from the api hasnt changed. I am a beginner in Android. Can some one help me solve it.
Below is my code:

> Main Fragment

```
Context context;
NewsItem newsItem;
ArrayList<NewsItem> newslist = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView;
Custom customAdapter;
ProgressDialog pDialog;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    super.onAttach(context);

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    new GetContacts().execute();



    return v;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Entertainment");

   // new GetContacts().execute();

  //  listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void > {

    DatabaseHandlerNewsItems DBHandler = new DatabaseHandlerNewsItems(getContext());


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void  doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandlder sh = new HttpHandlder();




        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?apiKey=7494e8d897474ddc9a4c13dcec8f78b1&category=entertainment");

        Log.e("Response", "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray jsonarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("sources");
               // String first_news = DBHandler.getcontact(0).getNews_description();


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                   //if(c.getString("description").equals(first_news))
                     //  break;

                    JSONObject object= c.getJSONObject("urlsToLogos");
                    String s = object.getString("medium");
                    String url =c.getString("url");


                    newsItem = new NewsItem(c.getString("description"), s,url);
                    DBHandler.addContact(newsItem);

                    //newslist.add(newsItem);
                }
                newslist = DBHandler.getallcontacts();
                customAdapter = new Custom(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_listview_row, newslist);






            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("error", "Couldn't get json from server.");



        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void avoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(avoid);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if ( pDialog!= null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

> Database handler

```
  NewsItem dbNewsItem;
private static final int DataBaseVersion = 1;
private static final String DataBaseName = "NewsDataBase2";
private static final String TableName = "Newslist";
private static final String ColumnTitle = "news_description";
private static final String ColumnImage = "Name";
private static final String ColumnId ="_id";
private static final String Column_url="url";


public DatabaseHandlerNewsItems(Context context) {
    super(context, DataBaseName, null,DataBaseVersion);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE ="CREATE TABLE " + TableName + "("
            + ColumnTitle + " TEXT,"+ColumnId+ "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Column_url + " Text,"+ColumnImage + " TEXT"
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE);





}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //String drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TableName;
    //db.execSQL(drop);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void addContact(NewsItem table) {
    SQLiteDatabase dB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ColumnTitle, table.getNews_description());
    contentValues.put(ColumnImage, table.getUrl_of_icon());
    contentValues.put(Column_url,table.getUrl());

    dB.insertWithOnConflict(TableName, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    dB.close();



}

public ArrayList<NewsItem> getallcontacts (){
    ArrayList<NewsItem> news = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TableName;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    cursor.getCount();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do {
            NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem();
            newsItem.setNews_description(cursor.getString(0));
            newsItem.setUrl(cursor.getString((2)));
            String url = cursor.getString(3);
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "");
            newsItem.setD(d);

            news.add(newsItem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return news;
}

public int getcount(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TableName;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    return cursor.getCount();

}

public NewsItem getcontact(int id ) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TableName, new String[]{ColumnTitle}, ColumnId + "=?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    NewsItem contact = new NewsItem(cursor.getString(0));
    return contact;

}
```

> Custom Adapter

```
private ArrayList<NewsItem> objects;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
public TextView TextView_newsitem;
ImageView ImageView_newsicon;
NewsItem i;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
int position;
String url;


public Custom(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NewsItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.objects = objects;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     this.position = position;
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview_row, null);
    TextView_newsitem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_newsitem);

    ImageView_newsicon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView_newsicon);
    ImageView_newsicon.setOnClickListener(this);

    i = objects.get(position);

    TextView_newsitem.setText(i.getNews_description());
    ImageView_newsicon.setImageDrawable(i.getD());
    url = i.getUrl();


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    getContext().startActivity(intent);


}
```

Comment: My suggestion is simply work on server response and try to get why news items not added.Adding both data(local and server ) at a time and filter according to your requirent ,make it complex.

Comment: okay got it thanks