# How to save server data in your application data base and retreive it

Tags: android

I am making a portal sort of an app . I have used an API to receive update that I push in the listview. But with every new update I lose out on the news piece from previous response. Therefore I created a Database that stores the previous news items. Now the problem is that I get duplicate copies since the database stores the response again if the update from the API hasn't changed. I am a beginner in Android.

Comment: Show your code bro..

Comment: @Neo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903300/generate-listview-from-items-received-as-responses-from-server-url

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to solve your problem

1. This is easy solution when ever u receive json response before insert that data in to sqlite database u delete ur all data of sqlite database
   then insert ur new response data in sqlite and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` methode to refresh the list.
2. This is something logical and depend upon ur json response. when ever u receive ur json response before insertion u check if data is available then update the data and if data is not available then insert the data.
   u can check this condition through ur primary key or use any unique key for this condition.